# Could not load drivers - Code 31

Tags: windows, windows-xp, drivers

I get this error when installing any network adapter on my computer:

The device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)

I have tried many different adapters and many different drivers. Any ideas?

OS: Windows XP Home SP3

Here is the Hardware IDs for the onboard NIC:

```
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1050&SUBSYS_2019107B&REV_02
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1050&SUBSYS_2019107B
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1050&CC_020000
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1050&CC_0200
```

[Device Manager Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G7KT.jpg)

Comment: You will need to use the driver for the adapter which is physically present in your system. Start with identifying which hardware that is, then add that to the post.

Comment: I have. I have tried 3 different adapters.. And i installed the drivers the adapter CURRENTLY in the system at that time.

Comment: I might add this: From device manager, go to the failed device. Right click, properties (now at the page with "Device status, this device is ... (code..)". Go to the tab "Details" and change "Device description" to "Hardware ID". Post those.

Comment: Added Hardware IDs

Comment: That is the ID of the Intel VE card (I can tell by the vendor ID, Intels ID is easy to memorise).  The rest indicates the specific version of that card, up to the revision. Normally I would search the net for the specific driver for this model (skipping any untrusted driver sites). However given that you have a lot of failed devices, you might want also want to check the chipset drivers for your motherboard. If those fail you get 'fun'.

Comment: Yeah I have already installed the chipset drivers. Any NIC card I put in (including wireless USB adapters) fail with the same error. So unless I get an answer I will try reloading windows.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some poking around, I found it had a recovery partition. After running this, The drivers loaded just fine!  Thanks for everyone's help!